# Error 400 con socket.io

Tags: nodejs, socket.io

Estoy realizando una conexión con [Socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v4/), para la configuración he seguido las recomendaciones de la documentación.

Todas las pruebas realizadas de manera local funcionaron sin problema alguno, por lo que se subio a un servidor para realizar pruebas y resulta que siempre se recibe un `400` entre errores de **CORS**, pero extrañamente si se llega a conectar y regresa un `id` del **socket**, al igual que tambien se desconecta y se conecta de manera variable, en ocaciones 1 o 2 desconecciones dentro de 1minuto y otras puede estar 5min sin desconectarse, pero si con los errores

### Configuración de mi servidor

```
    this.server = createServer(this.app);
    this.io = new ServerIo(this.server, {
      pingTimeout: 60000,
      cors: {
        origin: 'https://mydominio.example.com',
        methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
        credentials: true
      },
      
    });

  sockets() {
    this.io.on('connection', socketController);
  }

  listen() {
    this.server.listen(this.port, () => {
      console.info(
        'Servidor corriendo en puerto:',
        process.env.PORT,
        'Modo:',
        process.env.NODE_ENV
      );
    });
  }
  sockets() {
    this.io.on('connection', socketController);
  }

  listen() {
    this.server.listen(this.port, () => {
      console.info(
        'Servidor corriendo en puerto:',
        process.env.PORT,
        'Modo:',
        process.env.NODE_ENV
      );
    });
  }

const socketController = (socket: Socket) => {
  console.info('usuario conectado');
  users.conectarUser(socket);

  // Limpiar cuando alguien se desconeta
  socket.on('disconnect', reason => {
    console.info('Se nos desconecto', socket.id, reason);
    users.deleteUser(socket);
  });
};
```

### Configuración del lado del cliente

```
const socket = io('https://apidev.example.com', {
  withCredentials: true,
  auth: {
    'x-token': localStorage.getItem('x-token'),
    referencia,
  }
});
  
socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log(socket.id);
});

socket.on("disconnect", () => {
  console.log('se desconecto',socket.id);
});

socket.on('message', result => {
  console.log('mensaje recibido front', result);
})
```

### Errores recibido en front

```
GETwss://apidev.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=eAg2vZWiycFShsn1AAAG
[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 294ms]

AK-xV9Efy-vE5xyaAAAH PaymentSantander.tsx:50:14
XHRGEThttps://apidev.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OQMGkhv&sid=eAg2vZWiycFShsn1AAAG
CORS Missing Allow Origin

Firefox no pudo establecer una conexión con el servidor en wss://apidev.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=eAg2vZWiycFShsn1AAAG. websocket.js:44:26
Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en https://apidev.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OQMGkhv&sid=eAg2vZWiycFShsn1AAAG (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'). Código de estado: 403.
```

### Errores o razón de desconexión en el servidor

Los errores que mas recibo después de que se conecta un usuario es `ping timeout` y `transport close`. Cabe mencionar que no recargo pagina ni se pierde internet, se ha probado con múltiples redes buscando de las mas estables

también Sucede que realiza conexión y desconexión varias veces del lado del front.